# Grant permission to use the key in GKE

Tags: encryption, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to provision an encrypted disk for GKE dynamically.
But I really don't understand below part.

```
Grant permission to use the key
You must assign the Compute Engine service account used by nodes in your cluster the Cloud KMS CryptoKey Encrypter/Decrypter role. This is required for GKE Persistent Disks to access and use your encryption key.

The Compute Engine service account's name has the following format:

service-[PROJECT_NUMBER]@compute-system.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

Does it really necessary to grant "Cloud KMS CryptoKey Encrypter/Decryter" to Compute Engine Service account? Can I create a new SA and grant this role to it? The description said, the SA used by nodes. So I'm wondering if I can create a new SA and grant Cloud KMS role then use this SA to spin up GKE cluster. Then I think it should be available to provision encrypted disks for GKE.

official document below:

[dynamically_provision_an_encrypted](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/using-cmek#dynamically_provision_an_encrypted)

Comment: Yes, you can create a new service account, add roles and then assign this service account to Compute Engine. You are not required to use the default Compute Engine  Service Account. Note that the service account to spin up a cluster is not the same as the service account assigned to the cluster. They are different use cases. You can use the same service account, but this is not the normal case (principle of least privilege).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to follow this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/dynamic-provisioning-cmek) step by step:

1. create gke cluster ([check](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/gcp-compute-persistent-disk-csi-driver) Kubernetes Compatibility compatibility, I decided to stick with 1.14 this time), key-ring and key
2. deploy CSI driver to the cluster

   2.1. download driver `$git clone https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/gcp-compute-persistent-disk-csi-driver /PATH/gcp-compute-persistent-disk-csi-driver`

   2.2. configure variables for your project in `/PATH/gcp-compute-persistent-disk-csi-driver/deploy/setup-project.sh`

   2.3. create service account with `/PATH/gcp-compute-persistent-disk-csi-driver/deploy/setup-project.sh`

2.4. configure variables for driver deployment in `/PATH/gcp-compute-persistent-disk-csi-driver/deploy/kubernetes/deploy-driver.sh` and  `/PATH/gcp-compute-persistent-disk-csi-driver/deploy/kubernetes/deploy-driver.shinstall-kustomize.sh`

2.5. deploy CSI driver (I stick with stable version)

```
$./deploy-driver.sh
```

3. enable the Cloud KMS API
4. assign the `Cloud KMS CryptoKey Encrypter/Decrypter` role (`roles/cloudkms.cryptoKeyEncrypterDecrypter`) to the `Compute Engine Service Agent` (`service-[PROJECT_NUMBER]@compute-system.iam.gserviceaccount.com`)
5. create StorageClass

   ```
   $cat storage.yaml    
   apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1beta1
   kind: StorageClass
   metadata:
     name: csi-gce-pd
   provisioner: pd.csi.storage.gke.io
   parameters:
     type: pd-standard
     disk-encryption-kms-key: projects/test-prj/locations/europe-west3/keyRings/TEST-KEY-RING/cryptoKeys/TEST-KEY


   $kubectl describe storageclass csi-gce-pd
   Name:            csi-gce-pd
   IsDefaultClass:  No
   Annotations:     kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration={"apiVersion":"storage.k8s.io/v1beta1","kind":"StorageClass","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"csi-gce-pd"},"parameters":{"disk-encryption-kms-key":"projects/test-prj/locations/europe-west3/keyRings/TEST-KEY-RING/cryptoKeys/TEST-KEY","type":"pd-standard"},"provisioner":"pd.csi.storage.gke.io"}

   Provisioner:           pd.csi.storage.gke.io
   Parameters:            disk-encryption-kms-key=projects/test-prj/locations/europe-west3/keyRings/TEST-KEY-RING/cryptoKeys/TEST-KEY,type=pd-standard
   AllowVolumeExpansion:  <unset>
   MountOptions:          <none>
   ReclaimPolicy:         Delete
   VolumeBindingMode:     Immediate
   Events:                <none>
   ```
6. create persistent volume

   $kubectl apply -f pvc.yaml
   persistentvolumeclaim/podpvc created

   $kubectl describe pvc podpvc
   Name:          podpvc
   Namespace:     default
   StorageClass:  csi-gce-pd
   Status:        Bound
   Volume:        pvc-b383584a-32c5-11ea-ad6e-42010a9c007d
   Labels:        
   Annotations:

   ```
      kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"PersistentVolumeClaim","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"podpvc","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"accessModes...
              pv.kubernetes.io/bind-completed: yes
              pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: yes
              volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner: pd.csi.storage.gke.io
   Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
   Capacity:      6Gi
   Access Modes:  RWO
   VolumeMode:    Filesystem
   Mounted By:    <none>
   Events:
     Type    Reason                 Age                From                                                                                                           Message
     ----    ------                 ----               ----                                                                                                           -------
     Normal  Provisioning           31m                pd.csi.storage.gke.io_gke-test-cluster-default-pool-cd22e088-t1h0_c158f4fc-07ba-411e-8a94-74595f2b2f1d  External provisioner is provisioning volume for claim "default/podpvc"
     Normal  ExternalProvisioning   31m (x2 over 31m)  persistentvolume-controller                                                                                    waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "pd.csi.storage.gke.io" or manually created by system administrator
     Normal  ProvisioningSucceeded  31m                pd.csi.storage.gke.io_gke-test-cluster-default-pool-cd22e088-t1h0_c158f4fc-07ba-411e-8a94-74595f2b2f1d  Successfully provisioned volume pvc-b383584a-32c5-11ea-ad6e-42010a9c007d
   ```

And it's successfully provisioned.

Then I removed `Cloud KMS CryptoKey Encrypter/Decrypter` role from the `Compute Engine Service Agent` and persistent volume created at step 6 and tried again:

```
$kubectl apply -f pvc.yaml                                
persistentvolumeclaim/podpvc created

$kubectl describe pvc podpvc
Name:          podpvc
Namespace:     default
StorageClass:  csi-gce-pd
Status:        Pending
Volume:        
Labels:        <none>
Annotations:   kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
             {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"PersistentVolumeClaim","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"podpvc","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"accessModes...
           volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner: pd.csi.storage.gke.io
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:      
Access Modes:  
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Mounted By:    <none>
Events:
Type     Reason                Age                   From                                                                                                           Message
----     ------                ----                  ----                                                                                                           -------
Normal   Provisioning          2m15s (x10 over 11m)  pd.csi.storage.gke.io_gke-serhii-test-cluster-default-pool-cd22e088-t1h0_c158f4fc-07ba-411e-8a94-74595f2b2f1d  External provisioner is provisioning volume for claim "default/podpvc"
Warning  ProvisioningFailed    2m11s (x10 over 11m)  pd.csi.storage.gke.io_gke-serhii-test-cluster-default-pool-cd22e088-t1h0_c158f4fc-07ba-411e-8a94-74595f2b2f1d  failed to provision volume with StorageClass "csi-gce-pd": rpc error: code = Internal desc = CreateVolume failed to create single zonal disk "pvc-b1a238b5-35fa-11ea-bec8-42010a9c01e6": failed to insert zonal disk: unkown Insert disk error: googleapi: Error 400: Cloud KMS error when using key projects/serhii-test-prj/locations/europe-west3/keyRings/SERHII-TEST-KEY-RING/cryptoKeys/SERHII-TEST-KEY: Permission 'cloudkms.cryptoKeyVersions.useToEncrypt' denied on resource 'projects/serhii-test-prj/locations/europe-west3/keyRings/SERHII-TEST-KEY-RING/cryptoKeys/SERHII-TEST-KEY' (or it may not exist)., kmsPermissionDenied
Normal   ExternalProvisioning  78s (x43 over 11m)    persistentvolume-controller                                                                                    waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "pd.csi.storage.gke.io" or manually created by system administrator
```

and persistent volume stayed in pending status.

And, as you can see, in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/dynamic-provisioning-cmek) it's necessary:

> **Grant permission to use the key**
>
> You must assign the Compute Engine service account used by nodes in
>   your cluster the Cloud KMS CryptoKey Encrypter/Decrypter role. This is
>   required for GKE Persistent Disks to access and use your encryption
>   key.

and it's not enough to create service account with `/PATH/gcp-compute-persistent-disk-csi-driver/deploy/setup-project.sh` provided by CSI driver.

**EDIT** Please notice that:

> For CMEK-protected node boot disks, this Compute Engine service
>   account is the account which requires permissions to do encryption
>   using your Cloud KMS key. This is true even if you are using a custom
>   service account on your nodes.

So, there's no way to use only service account in this case without Compute Engine service account, because CMEK-protected persistent volumes are managed by GCE, not by GKE. Meanwhile, you can provide only necessary perdition to your custom service account to improve security of your project.

Comment: Okay, then I understood, this step is necessary to do.
Do you have any chance to deploy driver with workload-identity without put a key file on the instance? It's really not safe.